# How to compute a map for ALL houses in map to show the closest store

Tags: python

The question asked for a map that can show the close pizza store to every location on the map, and mark them with the order of the pizza in-store, therefore the map will look like a Voronoi Diagram.

Here is the question.

> In a town called Regulaville, and all the people living there have very strange habits. All the buildings have centers
> on a well-structured rectangular grid. The mayor of the town is at the most north-west corner of the town, and his
> house coordinates are `(0,0)`. And each building in town has coordinates `(i,j)` that indicate that his house is `i` km
> south and `j` km east from the mayor’s house for `i` and `j` are integers such that `0 <= i < r` and `0 <= j < c` for some
> integers `r` and `c`.
>
> A new brand of pizza came to town! They set up `n` stores in some of the buildings in town for some `n  10`. We store
> the coordinates of the pizza stores in a list. For example, a list of
> `[[10,20],[30,20],[40,50]]`
> represents three stores of pizza with Store 0 at `(10,20)`, Store 1 at `(30,20)` and Store 2 at `(40,50)`1
> . (Somehow
> the big boss of the pizza stores knows programming and he starts counting by 0 also.) There are no two pizza stores
> in the same location. All the people in Regulaville only eat pizza in their own homes by calling for delivery, and all the
> stores will deliver pizza by flying drones that will fly directly from the stores to the destination.
> In order to minimize the time and power used by the drones, the mayor ordered that every home must only order
> pizzas from the nearest store, unless there is more than one store with equal minimal distance to that home. For
> example, for the three pizza stores mentioned in the example above, the house at coordinates `(40,20)` will be
> closest to Store 1 with the nearest distance 10 km. Stores 0 and 2 will have more than 1 store with the same distance
> 30 > 10 km. Two utility functions `create_zero_matrix` and `m_tight_print` are provided for you.
>
> Write a function `pd_map(r,c,sites)` to compute a map for ALL houses in Regulaville to show the closest pizza
> store number to each house, where `r` and `c` are the height and width of the map respectively, and sites is a list of
> pizza store coordinates.
> The location of each house should be represented by the coordinates `(i,j)` such that `0 <= i < r` and `0 <= j < c`.
> You can assume the number of pizza stores will be less than or equal to 10 and their corresponding store numbers
> (i.e. labels) will be from 0 to 9. Below shows a sample usage of the function `pd_map()`.
>
> ```
> def create_zero_matrix(n,m):
>     return [[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
>
> def m_tight_print(m):
>     for i in range(len(m)):
>         line = ''
>         for j in range(len(m[0])):
>             line += str(m[i][j])
>         print(line)
> ```

Here is my code, I want to define a function to calculate the close store for each position and return the related number first. Then use this function to calculate all of the positions on the map. However, the result always return "none"

```
def pd_map(r,c,sites):
    map1 = create_zero_matrix(r,c)
    print (map1)
    for i in range(0, r):
        for j in range(0, c):
            elem = map1[i][j]
    def near_one(x,y,sites):
        res = []
        for n in range(len(sites)):
            res.append(math.sqrt((x-sites[n][0])**2 + (y-sites[n][1])**2))
            if res.count(min(res))==1:
                res.index(min(res))
            else:
                return X
    map2 = []
    for i in range(0, r):
        row = []
        for j in range(0, c):
            row.append(near_one(i,j,sites))
        map2.append(row)
    return map2
```

Comment: I have removed the [r] code tag as the question & code example seem to be python-specific.

Comment: it seem you make your cat make your function. Not so bad for a cat

Comment: by the way the line ` res.index(min(res))` does nothing

Answer (score 0):

1. The function returns something only when there are duplicate values in the list. Try to put two stores at the same place (no matter it is not permitted, python does not know it) and you will get the row number on each cell

Comment: Thanks, but I am sorry that I do not quite understand it, could you please explain some detail?